# Is there a pure CSS solution for freezing BOTH row & colum headers in a table?

Tags: css, freeze

I need to freze several rows on the top and several columns on the left of a huge table. Can this be done with pure CSS (and retaining a single large table), or must I split the table into three tables and use JavaScript to keep them in sync? Luckily all the cells have fixed width/height and I don't need to accommodate flexible cells.

Oh, as for browser support - IE7+ must be supported; preferably IE6 too (not sure if I'll need it or not); the others can be the latest version.

Comment: I'm not sure that there is, but you should mention what browsers you need to support as that might make a difference to the answer.

Comment: Not using purely CSS, you will need some javascript to make this work. See this -> http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/FreezePanes.aspx

Comment: Added browser support requirements.

Comment: @SamWarren - Yes, I can do it with JavaScript; I can think of several different ways even. But the question is - can I do it **without** Javascript?

Comment: If all the cells are of fixed dimensions, it's at least mostly possible (vertical I can cope with, horizontal scrolling with the header row acting correctly in sync with it I'm not sure about yet). But not advisable; it's a fairly fragile technique and I don't think IE6 would be supported and I'm not *quite* sure about IE7.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan - would you care to make that an answer?

Comment: @Vilx-: possibly some time, but not tonight... I need to go to bed, it being 1:30am.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan - Good night then! :)

Comment: What do you mean by "freeze"?

Comment: @Pumbaa80 He means [like this](http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html), except for more than just the top header row

Comment: Aha. Well, using a `thead` with more than one row is absolutely legitimate and solves the fixed rows (Might as well move certain rows from tbody to thead using JS). The fixed columns may be a problem though.

Comment: Did not know about thead. Very cool!

Comment: Hmm, indeed, that's a good find! I always thought that `<thead>`, `<tbody>` and `<tfoot>` were just for standards-compliance-maniacs. Apparently I was wrong! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an incomplete, kludgy solution that solves the column problem. But I thought someone may find it valuable. Several people have pointed out that "thead" might work for the headers, but no one has offered a solution on the columns:

http://jsfiddle.net/C8Dtf/20/

It works by one div to handle horizontal and another to handle vertical scrolling. The main problem is you can't see the horizontal scrollbar until navigating to the bottom (but mouse wheel scrolling works just fine). It works in IE7 and I used some display:inline hacks to pull that off. Note: I am only using javascript to create the tables.

My intuition after struggling with this for a bit is that *there is no pure CSS solution.* I simply can't imagine a way to sync scrolling in both directions.

Comment: I've seen attempts with setting `position: fixed` on the table cells, but that relies on viewport-relative coordinates. I suppose placing the table in its own iframe would do, but I'd rather take the Javascript route...

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, I'm not sure how that would work with both columns. That is, fixed or iframe would work for one direction, but you still want the frozen rows/columns to sync in the opposite direction. My brain hurts just thinking about it. Javascript really shouldn't be that bad. Anyway, thanks for the accept.

Comment: No problem. I don't think there'll be any better answer than "there is no pure css solution". The "fixed" solution... I guess you're right. I must have misunderstood something. A fixed element ignores any and all scrollbars, so it can't be any good.

Comment: OK, since you've accepted *this* one, I'll need to tackle the problem!

Comment: I thought much more thoroughly, tried a few assorted notions, but ended up deciding that with "common" CSS it's not possible; fixed top columns is easy, fixed left columns is easy, but the combination with scrolling is not possible; the attachment of the `position: absolute` just doesn't quite cut it. I wouldn't discount the possibility of managing it with the `table-*` values for the `display` property, but I've never used `table-column` and I'm not inclined to try it out now because it wouldn't fit in the IE support requirement. Ah well.